# CodeIgniter Pagination Last Page Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have been searching solution for my problem but i can't find an answer to it. My problem i believe is different than what normally others will be facing with codeigniter's pagination library.

I have 15 records inside my database and i wanna display 5 each page with the pagination. below is my pagination config :

```
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "main";
    $config["total_rows"] = $total_row[0]['total'];
    $config["per_page"] = 5;
    $config["uri_segment"] = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $config['num_links'] = 2;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<b>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

now the pagination display like this :

**1** 2 3 >

and if i navigate to page 2
my URL will be `http://blablabla.com/blablabla/2` and the data loaded correctly also the pagination will be

< 1 **2** 3 >

but if i go to the last page, the URL will be `http://blablabla.com/blablabla/3` which is fine, the data loaded also correct but the pagination will be

**1** 2 3 >

when i go to last page, the first page link will be highlighted. Is there any problem with my config?

Comment: Is this right? `$config['num_links'] = 2;` try changing it to 3?

Comment: I tried to change it and the result is still the same. I personally don't think so that's the issue because base on CodeIgniter's user guide :

$config['num_links'] = 2;
The number of "digit" links you would like before and after the selected page number. For example, the number 2 will place two digits on either side, as in the example links at the very top of this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change : 
`$config["uri_segment"] = $this->uri->segment(2);` 
to 
`$config["uri_segment"] = 2;` 
 because you just need to mention uri-segment numer here, if you put like this $this->uri->segment(2) system will take value at segment 2 as $config["uri_segment"] and if that segment is not exist it will highlight first page as current page.

Comment: Dude, thanks a lot... i thought if i put 2 there, i actually fix the segment = 2. Now it works! :)